# help with regex pattern for @123.ynynyn

Tags: regex

please help with this regex pattern @123.ynynyn

The pattern starts with a symbol @, just 1 character long

follow by numbers only, at least 1 character

follow by a period (.), just 1 character long

follow by a 6 character long letter string of only y or n

TIA

Comment: What flavor of regex is this supposed to be? Also, is this homework? This seems way too cut-and-dry.

Comment: @Chris, just javascript, I am adding extra characters to the pattern to rule out coincidental results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this regexp:

```
@\d+\.[yn]{6}
```

Comment: Depending on how the regex is being used, you might need to add `^` and `$` anchors around it.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it out.  I am hoping to match that pattern in any where in a string or if it might just happen to be the whole string.